# Selecting values from two columns and concatenating them into a column on a different table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench

I'm a bit new to SQL and trying to do what my description above says. This below is my query:

```
SELECT
     CONCAT (first_name, last_name) INTO full_name_variable
FROM
    table_1
WHERE
    phone_number = new.number;
```

It doesn't seem to work. However, when I use this query using `AS` it works. Like this:

```
SELECT
      CONCAT (first_name, last_name) AS full_name_variable
FROM
      table_1
WHERE
    phone_number = new.number;
```

I'd really appreciate the help

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: mysql doesn't support SELECT INTO, you need to use INSERT INTO with SELECT: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

Comment: Hey EzLo, I have a trigger that selects the values from the two columns if the conditions in the where clause are met, concatenates them and puts them into a new column in a new table

Comment: Thanks Jarek. Let me try it out

Answer (score 0):

Use explicitly `join` instead

```
SELECT CONCAT (first_name, last_name) INTO full_name_variable
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN tabke_2 t1 
       ON t1.phone_number = t2.number;
```

Or you may use `INSRET INTO` statement

```
INSERT INTO full_name_variable (full_name)
SELECT CONCAT (first_name, last_name) 
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN tabke_2 t1 
      ON t1.phone_number = t2.number;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the difference between a *variable* and a *column*.

`INTO` loads the value into a variable, that is available in the programming block you are using.  It is the same a `:=`.  So your first version is the same as:

```
SELECT full_name_variable := CONCAT(first_name, last_name)
FROM table_1
WHERE phone_number = new.number;
```

`AS` (which is actually optional), names a column in a result set.

Your code appears to be in a trigger where one does not normally return a result set.  My guess is that you want `INTO` or `:=`.  I prefer `:=` because I find it more intuitive for setting variables.